# Return a column with ON CONFLICT postgres query + mybatis

Tags: spring, postgresql, mybatis, ibatis

I have the following method in my mybatis mapper interface:

```
@Update("insert into user(key, name, age) values (10, 'Martin', 24) ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET age=50 RETURNING key")
@ResultType(value = Long.class)
Long updateUser();
```

The datatype of key is bigint.

However, I'm getting the following value: -1 (The result should be 10)

If I return the name itself and change the result type to String.class, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Mapper method has an unsupported return type: class java.lang.String
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is absurd. Changing the annotation from an @Update to @Select worked. :/